# IG metrics: Sum over all followers per country do not match the overall followers count

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, instagram, metrics

I am trying to figure out how to compare metrics for the `user_insights` endpoint (lifetime values) and `user` endpoint which I receive with the Graph API using Python. I get `followers_count` as a lifetime value on the level `user` and `report_date` and some nested "values" which are named `audience_country` and `audience_gender_age` for the same dimensions for endpoint `user_insights`. According to the IG reference, they are viewers distributions for countries and gender_age.

**I expect that the sum over all countries of audience_country equals followers_count but it does not.** (Same for the sums over gender_age <> country, even those are different. And they are pulled within 1 API request)
Do you have an explanation or a proper definition of the metrics? Unfortunately, the IG Graph API reference ([user fields](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/), [user_insights fields](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/insights#metrics-and-periods)) is not really exhaustive.

[Please find attached an example for a single business_user_id.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MImSb.png)

Comment: Facebook might not be able to determine a country or gender for every single one of those users. So as long as the data you are talking about does not explicitly deliver those numbers as well (as country / gender “unknown”, “unspecified”, or anything like that), I don’t see a reason why they _should_ add up.

Comment: From the docs for the corresponding facebook insights endpoint, and I'm sure the same for IG: "Demographic metrics, such as age, gender, and location, are only returned if there is data for 100 or more people."